# Using R to write arrays to firebase

Tags: json, r, post, firebase

Hello I have a script which generates some data and stores it in a data frame. I would now like to persist the dataframe to fire-base as an array, however I have an odd Issue I can't solve. Rather than storing the data as an array directly in the root of the file-system i.e parent/child/0 parent/child/1 the data is stored as /parent/child/some-random-chars/0, /parent/child/some-random-chars/1

Code to reproduce.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

POST("https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/parent/child.json", body = toJSON(mtcars, pretty = TRUE))
```

P.S: fyi the random string looks like this "-HfyD-w0LsgwvGgD8ukQ"

Comment: The random string is the auto-generated push Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately I figured out this was was because I was using POST not PUT. When you use POST firebase generates push id's and prefixes them to your data. When you use PUT it stores your data directly at the specified endpoint.